# Apply light to an object in openGL

Tags: object, opengl, light

I finished adding light to my object. But I have most of it of an example of internet and I want to understand what i'm doing. Can somebody explain me in detail what every step in the code does?

Fragment Program,

- Lightcolor : the light that we need (i took here red as example)
- Shininess : how many light we want to use, can also change the picture into a dark one
- gl_FragColor = to write the total color. But why do we do texture2D(..) + facingRatio * ...?

Vertex Program,

-Why gl_MultiTexCoord0.xy?
- And can someone explain how the lightdirection is calculated?

```
  varying vec2 Texcoord;
    uniform sampler2D baseMap;
    uniform vec4 lightColor;
    uniform float shininess;
    varying vec3 LightDirection;
    varying vec3 Normal;
    void main(void)
    {
float facingRatio = dot(normalize(Normal), normalize(LightDirection));
gl_FragColor = texture2D(baseMap, Texcoord) + facingRatio * lightColor * shininess;
    }






varying vec2 Texcoord;
uniform mat4 modelView;
uniform vec3 lightPos;
varying vec3 Normal;
varying vec3 LightDirection;
void main(void)
{  
   gl_Position =  gl_ProjectionMatrix * modelView * gl_Vertex;
   Texcoord =  gl_MultiTexCoord0.xy;
   Normal = normalize( gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);
   vec4 objectPosition = gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;
   LightDirection = (gl_ModelViewMatrix * vec4(lightPos, 1)).xyz - objectPosition.xyz;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Vertex shader**

I guess an old version of OpenGL is used and that's why gl_MultiTexCoord0.xy is used. Have a look at this [page](http://what-when-how.com/opengl-programming-guide/multitexturing-texture-mapping-opengl-programming/) to understand multitexturing and the built-in variable.

The variable `LightDirection` is easy to calculate, because it just refers to a vector from the object in direction to the light source. So, you can substract the position of the light from the current position (here: `objectPosition`). In this example, this is done in the eye-space, which has the advantage, that the view direction is easy to calculate (It's just vec3(0.0,0.0,1.0)).

The other lines are just some usual graphic transformations from the object-space of an vertex into the eye-space. To transform the normal into the eye-space, instead of the modelview matrix the normal matrix is needed. This is the inverse and transposed of the modelview matrix.

**Fragment shader**

The `facingRatio` defines how strong the current fragment should be enlightend. So, the scalar product between the normal and the light direction is used to measure it.
In the next line, the fragment color is calculated by reading a color for this fragment out of a texture and adding the color from the light to it.